# Java - Initial value of an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

in Java, what is the initial value inside an array. For instance,

My complete code:

```
public class Job{
    public Job(){
        String jobTitle = "";
    }//end constructor

    Job[] x = new Job[20];

}//end Job class
```

What is inside x array, at index 0, 1, 2...etc.?
Is every index filled with an empty string named jobTitle?
Also, is this an array of Objects? Specifically Job objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is an array of 20 `Job` objects, all of which are initialized to `null`. If you want to initialize each one to be a new object you can use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i] = new Job();
}
```

Comment: Just so I understand, this is putting inside each array index the empty String jobTitle? (I'm not sure if I'm asking this properly...). EDIT: by putting inside I mean, each array index is now a Job object which contains the empty string jobTitle.

Comment: @cupojava: this puts an instance of `Job` in each index. Your constructor will create an instance of `String jobTitle` that's given the empty string value for each object creation, but the instance of `String` is not saved since you don't hang on to the reference outside of your constructor.

Comment: Strings are auto-initialized to null, so if I'm understanding you correctly, the 'String' instance in each of the array indices is now null?

Comment: No, you're explicitly initializing your `String jobTitle` by setting it to the *empty string* (also written `""`).

Answer (score 2):

Each index in an array references `null` until it is initialized to another value.

So

```
Job[] jobs = new Job[2];
```

will hold 2 `Job` references, but they will both be `null`. That is until you initialize them

```
jobs[0] = new Job();
jobs[1] = new Job();
```

Note that in this case, you've declared `x` as an instance field of `Job`, so each new `Job` object you create will have a `Job` array with 20 `null` `Job` references.